# Preventing direct access to specific functions in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some methods in my Home controller such as authenticate. I don't want the user to access the authenticate by url.

So, if he types in directly http://domain.com/index.php/home/authenticate in the url bar, he should be denied access or redirected to login.

However, if he clicks on the login button in the main form, he should be able to be redirected to the authenticate method.

I have tried adding an underscore infront of authenticate, i.e,

```
private function _authenticate() {}
```

It works, i cannot access it by URL but neither can the button redirect to the authenticate method.

Answer (score 0):

`example.com/index.php/home/authenticate` does not access the `_authenticate` method of the home controller, it is looking for the `authenticate` method (they are two different things).

To redirect if not logged in you'd have something like:

```
public function authenticate()
{
  if ($not_logged_in)
    redirect('/login');
  else
    show_login_stuff_here();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put the underscore in front of the method name you cannot access it with that url because it doesnt access.

I think you are misunderstanding what a private method is for.

if authenticate is your login method

1. you should make authenticate public
2. on success log the user in and store in the session
3. at the beginning of the authenticate method check the session to see if the user is logged in and act accordingly, either redirecting or forcing the login etc

Comment: for example like @Matthew suggests

Comment: Okay. Suppose i have another function which pulls information from a form. If the user accesses the link directly, like http://domain.com/index.php/createaccount, the function create account will not have anything to work with. However if he clicked on the button on the form, it will post the data and i can access it through post. How can i restrict access to that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i have come accross a solution.

I have input validations on my forms which means, if the user omits a textbox, he is never going to be redirected to /createaccount

So if he does accesss the link directly, the textboxes get a value of 0 and if that happens, it means the user has accessed the link directly. I redirected the user to 404 page then.